$L|K$ is an algebraic extrension. If $K$ is perfect then $L$ is perfect.
My try:
Let $L|K$ be an algebraic field extension. K a perfect field.
Suppose that $L$ is not perfect, then there is some $f \in L[x]$ irreducible with multiple roots in some splitting field.
Let $\alpha$ be a multiple root of $f$ and let $M$ be a splitting field of $f$, so $\alpha \in M$, and the extension $M|L$ is finite, because $[M:L]\leq deg(f)!$, then $M|L$ is algebraic, therefore $M|K$ is algebraic.
Consider the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ in $K$, $m_\alpha \in K[x]$, as $K$ is perfect, then $m_\alpha$ splitts in different linear factors in the splitting field $M$.
Notice that for every field $K'$, $K \subseteq K' \subseteq L$, $K'|K$ is algebraic. So there is a minimal polynomial $m_\alpha '$ monic irreducible in $K'[x]$, and more important $m_\alpha '$ divides $m_\alpha $ in $M[x]$, hence, for every extension $K'|K$, $m_\alpha '$ splitts in linear factors.
Finally, if $m_\alpha$ is irreducible in $L[x]$ then $f(x)=rm_\alpha(x)$ for some $r \in L$, as $f$ is irreducible, contradiction, becaue $f$ was not separable.
If $m_\alpha$ is reducible in $L[x]$, let $m_\alpha '$ be the minimal polynomial, and again, as $f$ is irreducible in $L[x]$, then $f(x)=sm_\alpha ' (x)$ for some $s \in L$, contradicting the fact that $f$ was not separable.
Is my argument correct?

Did you mean "separable" rather than "algebraic" in your third line?

My mistake, I was assuming that L wasn't perfect.  I'will make the edit :)
